# Possible to use Linq outside a Repository without leaking provider and still filter inside a database?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, repository-pattern

Is using Linq to construct a query outside a Repository while still filtering data at the database possible without exposing/leaking Linq to Entities outside a repository?  Obviously I could construct lamba expressions as parameters to the Query() method or even specification objects, but I was hoping to somehow use Linq to create efficient ad hoc queries regardless of what data provider is used in the repository.

For example:

```
var myProductID = myRepo.Query()
                  .Where( p => p.color.Contains("green") )
                  .Select( p => p.ID.ToString() );
```

The concepts seem mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

> but I was hoping to somehow use Linq to create efficient ad hoc queries regardless of what data provider is used in the repository.

This idea is doomed to fail. See, the problem is that not every lambda expression is translatable by every LINQ provider into something that that provider can handle. That's the source of the dreaded "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method...." or the analogous exception message for other LINQ providers. There are expressions that LINQ to SQL can handle, but LINQ to Entities can't, and vice versa. Throw in similar issues for the LINQ provider in NHibernate.

In short, exposing a LINQy way to query through your repository is a leaky abstraction. Avoid, avoid, avoid.

Comment: Even worse some EF Linq queries *behave* differently when using same syntax as Linq to Objects (e.g. SequenceEqual vs == on a byte array) Very leaky abstraction indeed.